# CMake policy CMP0046, find_package(), and add_subdirectory()

Tags: cmake

We have a complicated CMake project that suffers from [CMP0046](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0046.html) since upgrading to CMake 3.  Here is the basic setup in the root `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Sqlite)  # Finds the system library at /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so
...
add_subdirectory(master)
```

Then in the `master/` sub-directory, the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(MASTER_DEPS sqlite)
...
add_library(master_lib OBJECT EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${MASTER_SOURCES})
add_dependencies(master_lib ${MASTER_DEPS})
```

The policy warning for CMP0046 is thrown for the `sqlite` dependency, yet it is found in the main `CMakeLists.txt` before the `add_subdirectory` is done.

I've attempted to rewrite our FindSqlite.cmake module several times.  Also, the warning goes away if I add `sqlite` source myself instead of using the `find_package` call like so:

```
add_library(sqlite
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlite3.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlite3.h
)
```

For reference, [here is our current FindSqlite.cmake module.](https://code.google.com/p/bitfighter/source/browse/cmake/Modules/FindSqlite.cmake)

**How do I make it not warn when finding the system library?**

I do not want to suppress the warning.

Comment: It would be nice if those who down-vote could explain why; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The command `add_dependencies` should only be used for CMake targets introduced with an `add_executable`, `add_library` or `add_custom_target` command.

Libraries found with `find_library` (as your `FindSqlite.cmake` does) should be linked with `target_link_libraries` instead. In your `master/CMakeLists.txt` use:

```
target_link_libraries(master_lib ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
```

The  CMP0046 warning should then go away.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I updated my question to reflect that I am using the `add_library` command.